# Set ACE target launcher's internal server port to Bluemix's random port number

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, apache-ace

I am currently trying to deploy and run an Ace Target on an IBM Bluemix CloudFoundry Java/Liberty buildpack but without much success.

**Symptoms:**
During the deploy/re-stage procedure, the ACE Launcher's internal server is started with a preset port number (default or set manually via cfg) whilst the Bluemix container is dynamically assigned a random port number. Port binding between both entities times-out and launch procedure fails.

**Option:**
The Bluemix random port is accessible via a sys. env. variable $PORT.

**Question:**
What would be the best/simplest approach to assign the freshly generated Bluemix's random port number to ACE Launcher's internal server?

Answer (score 1):

You can start the ACE launcher like this:

```
java -jar org.apache.ace.agent.launcher.felix.jar -v -s http://server:${PORT}
```

Where:

```
-v -- verbose, mainly so you can better diagnose what is going on
-s URL -- provides the launcher with the URL (which includes the port) of the server
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I am not sure if it is actually possible to use the java command directly on the remote cloud node other than possibly via an embeded script in a self exe JAR but maybe you were hinting at something else which I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how ACE takes arguments. The [documentation for the Java Buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#configuration-and-extension) explains how to provide custom JVM arguments that may be able to provide ACE with what it needs (perhaps `-s http://localhost:$PORT` as suggested by others).